# Extract background music having some files with voice

Tags: music, voice, background, radio, backgroundambience

Let's imagine I have some records of the radio program (for example, 20 different records). The background music is similar but voice is not. Suppose that audio is stereo.

Is there a way to extract this ambient just by adding some source files?

I think related question is here: [Given multiple audio files, can I extract background music that has different sound effects over it?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/31745/given-multiple-audio-files-can-i-extract-background-music-that-has-different-so). However, it's not completely the same.

Comment: by "records" do you mean vintage vinyl records of a radio program? also is your goal to discard the music and keep the voiceover or keep the music remove the voiceover?

Comment: I mean mp3 or wav files. The goal is to keep the music and remove the voiceover.

Comment: well there is an extensive way that I think would be possible but you would have to already have the music files in order to do it and if you already have them then there is no need to try to extract it.

Comment: @Timinycricket so? I have some files!

Comment: well if you have the background music files then to get the radio playlist without the talking you just need to put the songs in the same order and voila.

Comment: @Timinycricket , sorry for my explanations. no, I don't have original background... I want to extract the same background from many different files w/ the same background and different voice.

Answer (score -1):

Is the background music similar or exactly the same? If it's the same you can try some phase tricks which might work:

1. Take two recordings and make sure the background music lines up exactly the same.
2. Put one of the tracks out of phase. If the music is the same, this will cancel out but the voice over will stay.
3. Finally put the voice over out of phase with the original and you'll be left with a kind of clean version of the background, depending on the how similar the recording/music/noise etc is.

It's a long shot but it can work.

Comment: And are there any automatic solutions to do this? The work seems simple but monotonous.